# What is the grammatical function of "from across"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

In the following sentence what is the function of "from across"?

*Professionals from across the country are coming to London.*

I think it functions as a preposition but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"from across the country" means " from every part of the country. The preposition across normally describes movement from one side to the other: The children ran across the street without looking.
But it can describe slightly different movements. A totally different use can be found in: A TV series known across five continents. Here across means "in every part  of" all five continents.

Occasionally  you find "doubled" prepositions, often with "from": from under, from behind

- The cat came out from under the bed.
- The Wolf was looking out from behind the tree.

One can explain such double prepositions by inserting an omitted word or word group:

- The cat came out from its place/a place under the bed.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, *across the country* is the phrase serving whole as an adverb! Said that, *across* goes with *the country* and not with *from*. Of course, to answer you... **from is a preposition.**

> [across the country (adverb)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ACROSSTHECOUNTRY) - Extending throughout an entire nation

Comment: Exactly. It would be just the same if we replaced *across* with, say, *around, throughout*, etc. The preceding *from* is irrelevant, since one can say things like *"Social inequalities exist across the land"*.